# Where's the convert to comment button?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, moderator-tools, convert-to-comment

The convert to comment seems to have mysteriously vanished.

[image]

Now I realize there was a change in the way the convert to comment button behaviour - i.e., it would get disabled if there were existing comments on the post.

But in this case, there are no comments.

[image]

Is the length of the post causing the comment button not to show up?

Answer (score 2):

Even if the post is too long and will get truncated, you can convert it to a comment by using the "mod" link below the post. You'll get the usual menu of moderator actions on a post, including a radio option for *convert to comment*.

> mod -> convert to comment

Where the shortcut went I don't know, but my experience is that option didn't always show up as a suggested action anyway. Perhaps it has to do with how the post was flaged? If it was flagged "not an answer" it's more likely to have that as a suggested action with a shortcut button that page.

Comment: Yeah I know of the mod menu  - just curious if the button's not visible because of post size

Comment: @Sathya: Probably has to do with what it was flagged as actually. Was it flagged as "not an answer" or something else?

Comment: actually it wasn't flagged as not an answer - it was a "it needs mod attention -> other" flag - but I'm not sure if that matters

Comment: @Sathya: Yes I think it matters. I'm pretty sure the SE code monkeys have been working on optimizing moderator actions based on type of flags, so the action shortcut for "convert to comment" is likely only to show up if it was actually flagged as "not an answer".

Comment: let's hope that's not true - if so it's a pain, tbh

Comment: @Sathya Far as I know, Caleb's theory is right.