# Inconsistent presentation of "Convert to comment" option

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, convert-to-comment

I have seen a couple of these situations, today, where I have a "bad" answer ("bad" for whatever reason), that has been flagged, which would serve better as a comment. However, on the mod flag page there is no "Convert to Comment button",

> [image: Mod page - Convert to comment option not shown]

Yet on the question itself, under the **mod** link, the option *is* available:

> [image: Mod link - Convert to comment option shown]

Is it because, as can be seen in the screen shot, [this particular answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/210/how-do-i-calculate-the-cost-of-a-3d-print-once-its-done#answer-5704) was flagged as "Very Low Quality"? Unfortunately, I don't have a record of why the [other answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/how-to-set-a-new-homing-position-using-sofware-and-or-slicer-without-changing-ha/5871#5871) was flagged, as it has already been deleted and I don't believe that it is possible to see the flag any longer (is that right?).

Does the comment have to be flagged as "Not an answer" as [Caleb's answer/comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118139/wheres-the-convert-to-comment-button#comment310256_118158), to [Where's the convert to comment button?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118139/wheres-the-convert-to-comment-button), seems to suggest?

If so, that is mildly irritating, as a comment may not be correctly flagged, and *would* actual serve well as a comment, even though it was not flagged as such. It just means that more clicks (i.e. work) is required to convert the answer to a comment, than would be necessary, *if* the button was available *regardless* on the moderator page.

It would be nice if the convert to comment button was made available on the moderator page, whenever it is available under the question's mod link. That would seem to be more consistent, no?

Comment: It could be because the user posting the "answer" doesn't have enough rep to comment. The flag queue page could check this, but the menu allows you to override? I agree it should be consistent though.

Comment: The "Convert to Comment" option is not present when it is flagged as Very Low Quality. It has to be flagged as NAA. Note that VLQ is a post specific flag and NAA is an answer specific flag.

Comment: @ChrisF - I *think* that I converted an answer to a comment yesterday, using a button on the mod page, where the user had less rep than the comment threshold, so I don't think that that is the case.

Comment: @Greenonline - the convert to comment option certainly does override the 50 rep limit. I was wondering if the queue page checked it and didn't display the option.

Comment: @ChrisF - Sorry, just to clarify, By _queue page_ do you mean the Mod tools page? The button *was* displayed there yesterday for the low rep user, for [this answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5596/seemingly-random-lines-on-the-surface/5652#5652), but for today's low rep user the button wasn't, so I don't think that the user's rep determines whether the button is shown or not (on the mod tools page).

Comment: @Greenonline - ah. Yes that's what I meant.

Comment: @ChrisF My understanding is that it's just not an option ever. If you use the queue, it automatically goes on the question.